# Selecting all children of an element and fadeing them out using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadeout, children

I am using the following HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Project Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="z/baseCss.CSS">
    <script src="/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/baseJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id=header></div>
<div id=contain>
    <h1>Welcome to my web application</br>
  Please enter your name, click 'continue' and have fun</h1>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="John Doe"/>
    </form>
    <div class="awesome">Continue</div><br/>
</div>
<div id=footer></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and a code of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input")
        .focus(function(){
        $(this).css('outline-color','#559FFF');
        $(this).blur(function(){
            $(this).css("outline-color","#FF0000");
        });
    });
    $("input").click(function(){
     var value = $(this).val(function(){
         $(this).html("");
      });
    });
    $(".awesome").click(function(){
        b._slide(1000);
    });
    var b = $("div:nth-child(2)");
    alert(b);
});
```

My problem is that I can't figure it out how to select all children of `<div id="contain">` and just make them fade out when I click my div button which is the one with the "awesome" class.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
$(".contain").each(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});

but it didnt work also i tried: 
$(".contain").children(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Same result here.

What am I doing wrong? I only need to `fadeOut` the content of `<div id="contain">` and keep everything else the same as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use:

```
$("#contain").children().fadeOut(1000);
```

- `$(this)` is your selector
- [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) selects all the children of an element
- [`.fadeOut(1000)`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) fades out the current selection

Your attempts were wrong because:

```
$(".contain").each(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(1000); });
```

Selects all the elements with class `.contain` and hides them

```
$(".contain").children(function(){ $(this).fadeOut(1000); });
```

Selects the elements with class `.contain`, and then you're passing a function to `.children()` which it does not handle.

Note, in your case `contain` is an ID and not a class.

Comment: I'm glad I helped, good luck
שמח שעזרתי, בהצלחה :)
If this answer solved your issue, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

beside shangeing the "." to "#" form the jquery selector, if you don't need to insert anything else or display new content into `<div id="contain">`, you can just do this

```
$("#contain").fade(1000);
```

all the child will fade too